# How to include pre and post columns from existing columns/rows data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below (sample)

```py
id    date1        score1   score2   date2
101  2021-10-01     50       70      2021-09-01
101  2021-10-01     40       75      2021-11-01
102  2022-11-01     30       50      2022-09-01
102  2022-11-01     35       55      2023-01-01
103  2021-10-01     30       40      2021-11-01
```

Each `id` column has either one or two entries which depends on `date2`. Now each `id` combined with `date1` has two scores and two different dates (`date2`) associated to it. Now I want my score columns to be divided as `score1_pre` and `score1_post` based on `date2`. My resulting dataframe will look as below.

```py
id    date1      score1_pre   score1_post   score2_pre   score2_post   date2_pre  date2_post
101  2021-10-01    50             40           70            75      2021-09-01   2021-11-01
102  2022-11-01    30             35           50            55      2022-09-01   2023-01-01
103  2021-10-01                   30                         40                   2021-11-01
```

One way I could do is by creating a new column `pre/post` based on date1 and date2 and then have 2 dataframes (1 for pre and 1 for post) and finally concatenate these 2 dataframes based on column wise. But is there a more elegant way of doing this instead of having so many dataframes because my acutal dataframe size is huge and there are lot of score columns not just 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) after crafting helper columns:

```
cols = ['score1', 'score2', 'date']
m = df['date1'].gt(df['date2'])

out = (df.assign(lvl=np.where(m, 'pre', 'post'))
         .rename(columns={'date2': 'date'})
         .pivot(index='id', columns='lvl', values=cols)
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, ascending=False)[cols]
         .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}'), axis=1))
         .reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
    id score1_pre score1_post score2_pre score2_post   date_pre  date_post
0  101         50          40         70          75 2021-09-01 2021-11-01
1  102         30          35         50          55 2022-09-01 2023-01-01
2  103        NaN          30        NaN          40        NaT 2021-11-01
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am having couple of issues with this. As I was getting `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` error I changed `.pivot` to `.pivot_table`. For some reason I am not getting `date_pre` and `date_post` in the result. I am getting the result without `date` columns after commenting `.rename` and `.sort_index`.

Comment: This means you have duplicated combinations of id and `pre`/`post` cases. I assumed you had at most one `pre` and one `post` per id. Please update your example